# .htaccess url-rewrite conflicting with filename in root folder

Tags: .htaccess

I have Below .htaccess rule in my root folder :-

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^([^/]*)$ /user.php?user=$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^project/([^/]*)$ /project.php?id=$1 [L]
```

So, this basically do -> **http://example.com/user.php?user=stackoverflow** will be available from **http://example.com/stackoverflow** also, But when i browse **http://example.com/login.php** or any of my page, it gives **Internal Server ERROR 500.**

When i am using http://example.com/user/stackoverflow, everything **works fine**.

And my Guess is , **URL rewriting** is conflicting with **filename** in root folder, if it is, how can i disable filename checking for that, or any other better rule.

**Updated:** Rule [*Still not working*]

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -s [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -l [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule ^([^/]*)$ /user.php?user=$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^project/([^/]*)$ /project.php?id=$1 [L]
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You need to rewrite only none existing paths. use the following .htaccess rules

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -s [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -l [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule ^project/([^/]*)$ /project.php?id=$1 [L]    
RewriteRule ^([^/]*)$ /user.php?user=$1 [L]
```

Comment: Not Working I am still getting internal Server Error 500.

Comment: no even project is not working... earlier with http://example.com/user/stackoverflow it was working

Comment: try my update code, let see if /user/stackoverflow works first

Comment: Yes, file, user and project all of them are working fine. but i need it to be without user argument.

Comment: Nope! it's not working :(, i think i will stick with http://example.com/user/stackoverflow instead of http://example.com/stackoverflow.
Thanks a lot for your time DevZe0.